# how to resolve yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common error?

Tags: linux, centos, python, jquery

**how to resolve  yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common error?**

**on CentOS 6.5**

```
root@server [~]# yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.***.com
 * epel: mirror.***.com
 * extras: mirror.***.com
 * remi: remi.***.de
 * updates: mirror.***.com
 * webtatic: nl.repo.***.com

Replacing packages takes time, please be patient...
Error: Package 'php-common' is not installed.
```

**Error: Package 'php-common' is not installed.**

Comment: Why do you want to "replace" something that isn't even installed?

Comment: Don't cross post.  http://superuser.com/questions/742239/how-to-resolve-yum-replace-php-common-replace-with-php55w-common-error http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125035/how-to-resolve-yum-replace-php-common-replace-with-php55w-common-error

Answer (score -1):

please see here http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.5‎ as you know in centos 6.5 repository we cannot use yum install php-level OR like that

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything relevant to your question there.